# Generate composition for p2p video recording on Twilio

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio to in my app for a peer to peer video chat (using Small Group Room with max 2 participants). I have enabled video recording in my backend so I am able to record and save the videos but the problem occurs when I try to use the compositions API.

Composition API requires **video_sources** which is an array of video sources that will be used in the composition. Nowhere on the documentation it says how I can set the video source value. I can grab the **PARTICIPANT SID** and use that but it would be much much easier if I can use a value that is stored in my database. Users are also able to disconnect from the room and connect again so I need to keep track of video sources of a user.

Has anyone came across this issue?

This is a perfect example of what I mean by custom video_source

[Link to Twilio Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource?code-sample=code-compose-a-room-using-a-columnpip-layout-16&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

Answer (score 1):

The compositions API is only supported for Group Rooms.

[Comparing Room Types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#comparing-room-types)

Comment: I have updated my question. I used Small Group Room with max of 2 participants